# Option to open PuTTY from WinSCP in current path?

Tags: ssh, putty, winscp

I use WinSCP, and shortcut <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> to open PuTTY.

Is there an option somewhere to make the current path displayed by WinSCP to be set in PuTTY opening?

If I'm browsing in `/home/bob/work`
I wish to be logged in `/home/bob/work` when <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd>, not in the home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See WinSCP documentation on [Opening PuTTY in the same directory](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#putty_startup_directory).

A summary of the documentation:

> A complete PuTTY command line for this will be like (change the shell path according to your system and preferences):
>
> ```
> "%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\putty.exe" -t -m "%TEMP%\putty.txt" !`cmd /C echo cd "!/" ; /bin/bash -login > "%TEMP%\putty.txt"`
> ```